# Show Fragment in Activity - class cannot be instantiated

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android, just started learning.
My Android Studio doesn't support Blank Activity with Fragment.
So, I added it manually later on.

But the app stops in the emulator when I add a Fragment reference to main_activity.xml.

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

Fragment class:

```
package com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // Create some dummy data for the ListView.  Here's a sample weekly forecast
        String[] data = {
                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));
        ArrayAdapter<String> mWeekForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.list_item_forecast_text_view,weekForecast);


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_placeholder, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mWeekForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app.MainActivity">
<fragment class = "com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app.PlaceholderFragment"
    android:id ="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_placeholder" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Updated Logcat :

```
09-08 16:58:22.772 2244-2244/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
09-08 16:58:22.772 2244-2244/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
09-08 16:58:22.774 2244-2244/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-08 16:58:23.195 2244-2257/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8208(424KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(105KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 678KB/1117KB, paused 5.661ms total 73.994ms
09-08 16:58:25.607 2244-2252/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app W/art: Suspending all threads took: 28.005ms
09-08 16:58:26.088 2244-2257/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app W/art: Suspending all threads took: 30.701ms
09-08 16:58:26.772 2244-2252/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app W/art: Suspending all threads took: 183.063ms
09-08 16:58:26.824 2244-2244/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
09-08 16:58:27.106 2244-2252/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.965ms
09-08 16:58:27.353 2244-2244/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                                       --------- beginning of crash
09-08 16:58:27.354 2244-2244/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app, PID: 2244
                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app/com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                           at com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app.MainActivity@1bef27fa must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                                           at com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app.PlaceholderFragment.onAttach(PlaceholderFragment.java:109)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1019)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                           at com.example.urvashirohilla.sunshine.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: can you paste your logcat screen shot ?

Comment: @Shashank : Please add your Logcat.

Comment: @Himani Added the logcat, please check

Comment: @pawan Added the logcat please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you missed `must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener` on this line.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

Also, if using the support libraries, then AppCompatActivity is the recommended class to extend (which extends FragmentActivity itself)

In other words,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
           implements OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Then, if you get errors from that, then it's likely you're missing AppCompat themes in your manifest on that Activity

Comment: Your logcat literally has the error message written in it. You didn't implement the interface. Please update your question when you do, and I'll update my answer

Comment: yes but its still not working. if you want i ll post the updated logcat as well

Comment: Yes, please. Although, I might suggest a new question if the exception is different because my answer does address the one that was initially the problem

Comment: I see... Though, I did fix the earlier error. Is that the full exception? There should be multiple `Caused by` lines. One should hint at the actual problem

Comment: No, thats all I have in the logcat..:/

Comment: Strange. Your earlier error likely meant that the Activity was instantiated, then had an error when adding the Fragment. And now, I don't really have a suggestion other than try to use a `FragmentManager` via the Java code rather than loading a Fragment from the XML

Comment: implementing 3 OnFragmentInteractionListener  methods worked for me mate..Thanks..!!

Comment: 3 methods? You should only need to implement `onFragmentInteraction` unless you added more

Comment: Got it..I accidently created three methods inside OnFragmentInteractionListener.. interface, now it works with only onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri).

Answer (score 1):

**add compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24:2.0' in build.gradle**

AppCompatActivity inherits from FragmentActivity so if you need to handle Fragments you can (via the Fragment Manager). AppCompatActivity is for ANY API, not only 16+ (who said that?). You can use it by adding compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24:2.0' in your Gradle file. I use it in API 10 and it works perfect.

**Create a class extending AppCompatActivity;**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        RegistrationFragment registrationFragment = new RegistrationFragment ();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, RegistrationFragment).addToBackStack(null).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

}
```

**RegistrationFragment is the name of fragment which should extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment;**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


    public class RegistrationFragment  extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_registration, container, false);
            return parentView;
        }


    }
```

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' is already in the bulid.gradle and i guess version wont make any difference. The error persists..